# Proving that the limit of $1/x$ as $x$ approaches negative infinity equals $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that the limit of $1/x$ as $x \to -\infty$ equals $ 0$.

I get stuck in trying to find a proper epsilon. I know that it is supposed to be $-1/\epsilon$ but I don't understand how to manipulate the inequality $\epsilon > -1/x$.

Comment: Mh, I doubt that $\epsilon$ can be $-1/\epsilon$...

Comment: Well, if $\epsilon=i \, \dots$

Answer (score 1):

> Prove
>
> $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, we need to choose a $\delta >0$ such that if $x < -\delta$ then $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-0\right| < \varepsilon$.

Suppose $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-0\right| < \varepsilon$. Then, $-\varepsilon <\dfrac{1}{x}-0< \varepsilon$. As $x<0$, we see that the first inequality can be rearranged to

$$-\varepsilon <\dfrac{1}{x} \implies -x>\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\implies x<\frac{-1}{\varepsilon}$$

Therefore, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we are given, it is ensured that $\left|\dfrac{1}{x}-0\right| < \varepsilon$ so long as we choose $-\delta < \dfrac{-1}{\varepsilon}$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to achieve

$$x<-M\implies \left|\frac1x-0\right|<\epsilon,$$

which is

$$x<-M\implies x<-\frac1\epsilon,$$ as $x$ is negative.

Taking $M=\dfrac1\epsilon$ is a possible choice.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $x<-N$ where $N$ is chosen so that $N>0$ and $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Note that $-x=\lvert x\rvert$. So $\lvert x\rvert>N$. Can you finish the argument from here?

Comment: wouldn't it be 1/x < epsilon?

Comment: I'm sorry did I make a mistake? If you want to exclude the $N$ from the argument then yes you can choose $x<\frac{-1}{\epsilon}$ then $\lvert x\rvert=-x>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: not sure but i can write out my scratch work and you can point out my mistake.  x<N s.t |1/x|<e since x is less than 0, |1/x|=-1/x.  So now i have -1/x<e which i rewrite as x>-1/e but that can't be write since i need -1/e t0 be bigger than x

Comment: There appears to be an error in the inequality. Notice that if you want $\frac{-1}{x}<\epsilon$ then you need $\frac{1}{x}>-\epsilon$ and finally $x<\frac{-1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: glad to have located the error.  i think I'm having trouble with the sign of inequalities when i divide with negative unknowns.  if you have 1/x < -e … wouldn't you have x > -1/e since you divided by a negative epsilon?

Comment: But you also inverted the fractions which changes the direction of the inequality again.

Comment: but thats only when both sides share the same sign. for instance if a>b are both positive or negative then it holds that 1/a<1/b.  In this case -1/x is negative and e is positive.

Comment: I think both $\frac{1}{x}$ and $-\epsilon$ have the same sign since $\epsilon>0$ and $x$ was a negative number chosen to satisfy $\frac{-1}{x}<\epsilon$.

Comment: makes sense. i appreciate the helps. thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.